# Instagram APINotAllowed Error

Tags: python, api, instagram

I'm learning APIs and was testing with Instagram's API.

Currently, I have an client in sandbox mode and an access token with public_content scope. I created another instagram account that is set to private profile. This new account is a sandbox user for the client.

This is my code.

```
import requests
import json
parameters = {'ACCESS_TOKEN':'4831128049.31d6072.13cfcadf494344cba7d7f47f18f8ba97'} #modified fake access for question sake
response = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/{i-put-the-user-id-here}/self/media/recent?access_token='+parameters['ACCESS_TOKEN'])
json_data = response.json()
print(response.status_code)
print(json_data)
```

But I keep getting this.

```
{
    'meta':{
        'code':400,
        'error_type':'APINotAllowedError',
        'error_message':'you cannot view this resource'
    }
}
```

Edit 1: But this works if the user is the owner of the access token, that is it works perfectly for my own account but not for other private profiles that is also a sandbox account.

Am I doing something wrong?
If this is not possible, then how are there other 3rd party apps doing it? like Flume for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get private user via API even if you are following that user, this behavior changed last year with API policy. `APINotAllowedError` is expected response when trying to access a private user.

Comment: offtopic here but was wondering if you have any info if the current api will get deprecated and be replaced with the new one with Graph?